# About creating new Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I am practising some android development. I created a button in the main activity that opens second activity:

I use this code for the button:

```
 this.detailsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.details_btn);
    this.detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent k = new Intent(arg0.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class); 
            startActivity(k);
        }
    });
```

This code works properly as it opens the second activity. I also added a button that leads back to main activity in DetailsActivity.

```
this.mainListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_list_btn);
    this.mainListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent k = new Intent(arg0.getContext(), MainActivity.class); 
            startActivity(k);
        }
    });
```

This also works properly. My question is should I create new Intent each time I press whatever of the buttons as it is looks like it needs some time to open the new activity?

Is there a way to access the intent which is already created instead of recreating it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624338/android-return-to-previous-activity-without-calling-finish
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int

Comment: Creating an `Intent` object doesn't take any significant amount of time. The time it takes to open the activity is used by whatever code you've got in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`. You might want to look there if you are looking to optimize your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only call `finish()` into `DetailsActivity`

```
this.mainListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_list_btn);
    this.mainListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           finish();
        }
    });
```

---

> This also works properly. My question is should I create new Intent
>   each time I press whatever of the buttons as it is looks like it needs
>   some time to open the new activity?

You current application works fine, I agreed. But what will happen is, new Activity will get added into application stack on each time when button pressed. That should not be happen in your case.

Comment: Works perfectly and it is the right thing what I need for my app. I have a list of details so after they are reviewed the details activity should be closed and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access activity previously opened also you can call by onBackPressed(); function to previous activity.

Comment: You should not call '`onBackPressed()` to finish an `Activity`. Just call `finish()`. `onBackPressed()` is called by the Android framework.

Comment: finish() is destroys the current activity. İf you call finish() method after startActivity(), you shouldn't call onBackPressed() and it's not work because the previous activity is destroyed.

Comment: If you call `onBackPressed()`, all that does is call `finish()` on the current activity. But as I said, this method is intended to be called by the Android framework, not by your actvity. It is available so that your activity can **override it** if necessary, not so that you can **call it**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the activities to be present and do not want to call finish(), then you can simply bring back existing activity to front using

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);   
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```